# Laravel Passport Not Returning Token

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-passport

I've created an authentication controller using laravel passport, but the result is not what it usually is. variable `$token = $user->createToken('TestApp')->accessToken;` does not generate tokens in the `oauth_access_tokens` table but instead creating token in the `personal_access_token` table

My registration controller is

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required|unique:users,username',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
            'phone' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);            
        }

        $input = $request->all();

        $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);

        $user = User::create($input);
        
        $verifyUser = UserVerfication::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'token' => sha1(time())
        ]);
        \Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VerifyMail($user));
        
        $token =  $user->createToken('TestApp')->accessToken;

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Registration Success',
            'data' => array('APItoken' => $token, 'user' => $user)
        ], 200);
    }
```

And The result :

```
"APItoken": {
      "name": "LinwokApp",
      "abilities": [
         "*"
      ],
      "tokenable_id": 13,
      "tokenable_type": "App\\Models\\User",
      "updated_at": "2021-09-22T08:55:12.000000Z",
      "created_at": "2021-09-22T08:55:12.000000Z",
      "id": 11},
```

Comment: did you add this `'Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,'` in `app.php` providers array?
   and  did you change `api->driver` to `'passport'`in `auth.php`in guards array?

Comment: @JEJ yes, i have done everything

Comment: @JEJ `'api' => ['driver' => 'passport', 'provider' => 'users', 'hash' => false,],`

Answer (score 38):

I do not know if the question is still valid, but I had the same problem and found a solution.

Check out from what namespace you have HasApiTokens.

I used:

> use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

instead of

> use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

this was causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

Everything same correct.In your User Model,you should call 'use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens' instead of 'use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens'.By Default Laravel Configure with Sanctum.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

When you use Laravel Passport, you have to replace "use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;"
with "use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;" in the User.php

Comment: This doesn't seem to add any new information to the already-existing answers. [Check this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to write an answer

Answer (score 1):

I am using Laravel 10

Very same problem I faced and after so much research I came to know that I forgot to install Passport

To install I ran following command

```
php artisan passport:install
```

One more thing just check if user model is using

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
```

not

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
```

Answer (score 0):

It means you are using Sanctum not Passport

Change

```
$token =  $user->createToken('TestApp')->accessToken;
```

to

```
$token =  $user->createToken('TestApp')->plainTextToken;
```